# Using a custom field with the month_links tag

Tags: custom-fields, channel, entry-date

Does anybody have a way of using the **channel:month_links** tag (to create a list of links to monthly archive pages) that takes it's date point from a *custom* date field rather than the entry_date field? I have a channel where the user can enter details of journalistic articles that they have written; one of the channel fields is {publication_date}. I want my month_links to be in the vein of:

### Articles published in...

- June 2013
- July 2013
- August 2013
- etc

so I need the tag to hook into the publication_date not the entry_date. So far I can't find a way.

I realise that I could insist that users use the entry date field as the publication date, but the downside of that is that I can't change the field name (and 'entry date' is not a good label for the field, it's misleading), nor can I add field instructions.

Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility might be to use an “event” plugin such as Low Events or EEvent Helper, peruse the [‘events’ tag at devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/events/) for enlightenment…

Comment: Thanks 3Easy. Yes, I guess that would be a way to do it. Indeed, I'm already using Low Events on a different part of the site, so it's already in the mix and ready to roll. I just wondered if there was a way of doing, natively, what seems like it should be easy. I guess I just have to accept that it needs third-party help and go the Add-On route after all. (And plop a feature request over to EllisLabs).

Answer (score 2):

If you can overcome your objections to using the native Entry Date I'd definitely opt for using that...  However, if you want to essentially rebuild the month_links functionality yourself, you could do this with Stash (yet again!).

Try something like this, using two nested `get_list` tags: (if you're using an embedded view template you won't need the `stash:parse` tags, but they're handy here when setting and getting in the same template...)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" dynamic="no"}

    {exp:stash:append_list name="months-to-output" trim="yes"}
        {stash:month-num}{publication_date format='%m'}{/stash:month-num}
        {stash:month-title}{publication_date format='%F %Y'}{/stash:month-title}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}

    {exp:stash:append_list name="articles-by-month" context="{custom_date format='%m'}"}
        {stash:the-title}{title}{/stash:the-title}
        {stash:the-link}{url_title_path=articles}{/stash:the-link}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- ==============================
TEST OUTPUT 
=================================== --} 

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    <ul>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="months-to-output"}
        <li>
            <h2>{month-title}</h2>
            <ul>
            {exp:stash:get_list:2 name="articles-by-month" context="{month-num}"}
                <li><a href="{the-link}">{the-title}</a></li>
            {/exp:stash:get_list:2}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: James, I think that since I've already got Low Events in place on the site and since I can co-opt it into this particular task, I'll go that route this time. But your Stash solution (oh, Stash, is there anything you *can't* do?) is very interesting -- even if it does make my head hurt -- and I'll keep it in a drawer for a time when I'm not using Low Events (and don't want to spend the cash on it just to get the Archive links I want). Cheers.

Comment: BTW I take on board your recommendation to use the native entry_date field, but my objections still stand: the name (Entry Date) is a misnomer that is likely to mislead and confuse the site editor, and I can't mitigate that by adding field instructions. Also, I have several other channels that either use a native custom 'date' field or a Low Events field for date-related channel data, and thus the editor never actually has to bother explicitly setting the entry date. To require it in this one case would create some UX dissonance I think, so I wish to avoid it..